# Raw query to eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I am converting the following query to eloquent :

```
select * from db.users
    Where (linker is null) and (admin_published is null)
union
select * from db.users
    Where (linker is not null) and (linker_verified = 2) and (admin_published is null)
```

Eloquent :

```
\App\User::where('linker', null)->
Where('admin_published', null)->
orWhere('linker','!=',null)->where('linker_verified', '=',2)->
orWhere('admin_published','!=', 1)->get();
```

It does not give me the records where `linker` is not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel gives you eloquent method `union()`. Have you tried this? You can use `whereNull('column')` and `whereNotNull('column')`

```
$first_query = \App\User::whereNull('linker')
    ->whereNull('admin_published');

$users = \App\Users::whereNotNull('linker')
    ->where('linker_verified', '=', 2)
    ->whereNull('admin_published')
    ->union($first_query)
    ->get();
```

[Lara docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#unions).